# Highcharts chart moves up from x-axis on drill down

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts to draw a chart of my data.When I am having a column chart and when I drill down in it, after drill down the chart moves up from the x-axis. This is the x-axis and y-axis settings:

```
xAxis: {
labels: {
  rotation: -20,
  align: 'right'
  }
},
 yAxis: {
  min: 0
}
```

[image: This is before the drill down]
[image: This is after the drill]
Let me know if anybody has any solution for this.

Comment: can you post it in jsfiddle or something, that will help us to give solution faster

Comment: Please update yor highcharts to the newest 4.0.4 version, because it was buggy in the past.

Comment: That worked..! I changed the highcharts version. Thank you very much Sebastian Bochan and strikers.

Comment: @SebastianBochan You should probably post that as an answer.

Comment: As I see I have already you did.

Answer (score 0):

PLease update the version of the highcharts to 4.0.4, because the previous one had some bugs. It worked for me.