# angular2-highcharts x axis moves up on drilldown

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am using angular2-highcharts v0.5.5, which installs highcharts v5.0.14.  When I do a drilldown on a column chart, the columns sometimes no longer align with the x axis.  I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063540/highcharts-chart-moves-up-from-x-axis-on-drill-down) which seems to indicate an update fixed an older version.  Is there a version I should use instead of 5.0.14?  Thanks!

EDIT: This seems to happen on smaller screen/window sizes.  I haven't been able to replicate when the browser window is full size.

Comment: can you make a plnkr recreating the issue?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a way to port the angular2 stuff to a plunker/fiddle in any reliable way

Comment: you can fork off of the angular2-highcharts demo. http://plnkr.co/edit/IuwjpPB1YQW1T7i4B8SZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I have created drilldown charts using angular2-highcharts by including module drilldown.

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule, Component }    from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }          from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ChartModule }            from 'angular2-highcharts'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styles: [`
      chart {
        display: block;
      }
    `],
    template: `<chart [options]="options"></chart>`
})
class AppComponent {
    constructor() { 
        this.options = {
            chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33,
            drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 24.03,
            drilldown: null
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.38,
            drilldown: null
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.77,
            drilldown: null
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 0.91,
            drilldown: null
        }, {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            y: 0.2,
            drilldown: null
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            data: [
                [
                    'v11.0',
                    24.13
                ],
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    17.2
                ],
                [
                    'v9.0',
                    8.11
                ],
                [
                    'v10.0',
                    5.33
                ],
                [
                    'v6.0',
                    1.06
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.5
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }
        };
    }
    options: Object;
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ChartModule.forRoot(
      require('highcharts'),
      require('highcharts/modules/exporting'),
      require('highcharts/modules/drilldown'),
    )
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent]
})
class AppModule { }


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hxyqOWU6ePurXFWH9v2e?p=preview) demo